# $\tilde \Omega$ for division by logarithmic factor

Tags: asymptotics, notation

Is $\Omega \left(\frac{n}{\log{n}} \right)\subset \tilde\Omega(n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\tilde\Omega$ isn't completely standard, and should be explained whenever used. Usually it hides logarithmic factors, and in that case, what you wrote holds.

Comment: What about in the abstract of a paper? Seems like explaining would be too verbose.

Comment: In the abstract you can skip the explanation, but be sure to mention it in the body of the paper.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks. I'll just footnote the abstract.